# Electron app, plantUml generates images in Html code (jquery), button to download it but there isn't any source/href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron, plantuml

#### Im developing a simple electron APP.

[Project with all code in GitHub](https://github.com/JoseRodrigues443/FirstElectronApplication)

Basically that is a plantUml viewer, you put the PlantUml code in the text area, press the button and a plantUml diagram appears ate the side bar.

[image]

> Simple.

### how it Works

- In the HTML code insert a image with the tag uml, with the palntUml code:

  ```
  <img uml='
  Bob->Alice : foo
  Bob<--Alice : foo
  '>
  ```
- Run this method, and all the images with that tag will be altered:

  ```
   // I use this method to transform the plantUml code into a image
  plantuml_runonce();
  ```

[PlantUml jQuery module](http://plantuml.com/jquery)

### Problem:

Well it works, it renders the image, but that image isn't saved in disk is embedded in the HTML, so I don't know the source of the image (**href**) to add a link/button to download the image:

```
<a href="WHAT IS THE REFERENCE TO DOWNLOAD THE IMAGE IN THE HTML??" download>
```

The problem is that electron also don't support right click, when I open the index.html in a browser I can do right click and download the image, but in here I cant...I need to add a button or a link to download the image, but I don't know how to access (maybe use a id in the image and use JavaScript to download?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an `id` to the image and write some JavaScript to download the `src`.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = document.getElementById("someid").src;
link.href = document.getElementById("someid").src;
link.click();
```